# Google Trends equivalent for Bing, Yahoo, Ask.com

Tags: cross-compiling, google-trends

Looking into relationships between keyword searches in google trends and consumer ETFS. Does anyone know where I can generate the same sort of data for other popular search engines like Bing, Yahoo, Ask.com, and any others? Additionally, any insights on how to weigh google trends data along with the other search engines would be helpful. Clearly some search engines will provide more valuable insights than others, however, I am unsure if doing a weighted average by sample size is oversimplifying the matter.

Any advice helps, Thanks!